# How to evaluate environment variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to use the value of a local environment variable stored in an .env file in a Dockerfile, pretty much as you can do with docker-compose. My script looks like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $(pwd)/.env

echo "Building new training container image..."
docker build \
        -t "rasa_training_img" \
        --build-arg RASA_VERSION \
        ./rasa-training

echo "Build finished. Running container..."
docker run \
        -v $(pwd)/rasa-server:/app \
        --name "rasa_training_cont" \
        rasa_training_img
```

And the `Dockerfile`looks like this:

```
# FROM rasa/rasa:1.9.4-spacy-de
FROM rasa/rasa:$RASA_VERSION-spacy-de

COPY ./utils /training-utils

# install necessary python packages
USER root
RUN pip install -r training-utils/requirements.txt
USER 1001

# execute training steps script
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
CMD [ "training_steps.sh" ]
```

When I try to run it like this, it produces the following output:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM rasa/rasa:$RASA_VERSION-spacy-de
invalid reference format
```

Also tried it with curly braces:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSION}-spacy-de
invalid reference format
```

Is there a way to access the value of the variable (like one can do with docker-compose)?
I know I could basically replace my script with a docker-compose file but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can be passed as build arguments while issuing the `docker build` command.

In your Dockerfile, above FROM line add the below.

```
ARG RASA_VERSION=${RASA_VERSION}
# FROM rasa/rasa:1.9.4-spacy-de
FROM rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSION}-spacy-de
COPY ./utils /training-utils

# install necessary python packages
USER root
RUN pip install -r training-utils/requirements.txt
USER 1001

# execute training steps script
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
CMD [ "training_steps.sh" ]
```

In your docker command do

```
docker build --build-arg RASA_VERSION=${RASA_VERSION} -t imagename:tag .
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that does not work. Already tried it at some point, sorry did not mention that: ```Step 1/8 : ARG RASA_VERSION=${RASA_VERSION}
Step 2/8 : FROM rasa/rasa:${RASA_VERSON}-spacy-de
invalid reference format
```